# read.table with variables and numbers in same column

Tags: r

Is it possible to use `read.table` to read a data set in which variables and numbers appear in the same column?  Here is an example that does not work, followed by `matrix` which does work:

```
aa <- 10
bb <- 20

my.data1 <- read.table(text = '
    aa   0
    0    bb
', header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my.data1

# matrix returns desired output
my.data2 <- matrix(c(  aa,   0,
                        0,  bb  ), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)    
my.data2
#     [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   10    0
# [2,]    0   20
```

My guess is that `text` converts `aa` and `bb` to text, but can this be avoided while still using `read.table`?

```
str(my.data1)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "aa" "0"
 $ V2: chr  "0" "bb"
```

Comment: This is kind of unclear. In general, though, any atomic object can only have one class, this includes vectors, matrices, and a variable in a data.frame, so you can't have both numeric and character values in any of those structures.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas.  Consider posting that as the answer.  Although, why does it work when using `matrix`?

Answer (score 2):

The `text` argument to the `read.table` function doesn't convert your input to a character string, it's the (single) quotes that create a string literal or string constant as the R documentation for quotes (do `?Quotes` in R) explains:

> Single and double quotes delimit character constants. They can be used interchangeably but double quotes are preferred (and character constants are printed using double quotes), so single quotes are normally only used to delimit character constants containing double quotes.

The `aa` and `bb` in the `matrix` command are *symbols* in R as they are not quoted and the interpreter will find their values in the global environment.

So to answer your question: no, it's not possible to do this unless you use a function like `sprintf` to subsitute the values of `aa` and `bb` in the string. For example:

```
my.data1 <- read.table(text = sprintf('
    %f   0
    0    %f', aa, bb), header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

But this is not something that would be very common to do!